# java.io.IOException: couldn't start recording

Tags: android

I am using voice search feature in my app.For this I used to start speech Recognizer using Intent like:-

```
iSpeechIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
iSpeechIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,  RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
iSpeechIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, "voice.recognition.test");      
iSpeechIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 3);

                                  sr.startListening(iSpeechIntent);
```

Now I got this exception  :

```
-ERROR|12-11 18:56:44.035|4053|4067||RecognitionControllerImpl|Caused by: java.io.IOException: couldn't start recording
ERROR|12-11 18:56:44.035|4053|4067||RecognitionControllerImpl|  at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:324)
ERROR|12-11 18:56:44.035|4053|4067||RecognitionControllerImpl|  at com.google.android.voicesearch.speechservice.RecognitionControllerImpl$1.handleMessage(RecognitionControllerImpl.java:251)
ERROR|12-11 18:56:44.035|4053|4067||RecognitionControllerImpl|  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
ERROR|12-11 18:56:44.035|4053|4067||RecognitionControllerImpl|  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
ERROR|12-11 18:56:44.035|4053|4067||RecognitionControllerImpl|  at com.google.android.voicesearch.speechservice.RecognitionControllerImpl.recordAndSend(RecognitionControllerImpl.java:522)
ERROR|12-11 18:56:44.035|4053|4067||RecognitionControllerImpl|  at android.media.AmrInputStream.read(AmrInputStream.java:88)
ERROR|12-11 18:56:44.035|4053|4067||RecognitionControllerImpl|  at com.google.android.voicesearch.speechservice.RecognitionControllerImpl.access$100(RecognitionControllerImpl.java:82)
ERROR|12-11 18:56:44.035|4053|4067||RecognitionControllerImpl|  at com.google.android.voicesearch.speechservice.AudioBuffer.access$000(AudioBuffer.java:34)
```

My question is How I can handle this exception using Uncaught exception handle?

Comment: Hi Deepak, I am having the same problem wondering if you managed to figure out the cause/solution?

Answer (score 0):

Change `ecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM`

Into `RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM`

Maybe this is causing error.

And delete the following line-

```
sr.startListening(new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want an `UncaughtExceptionHandler`, HTH:

```
private UnexpectedTerminationStuff mUnexpectedTerminationStuff = new UnexpectedTerminationStuff();
private class UnexpectedTerminationStuff {
    private Thread mThread;
    private Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler mOldUncaughtExceptionHandler = null;
    private Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler mUncaughtExceptionHandler = new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
            // gets handled in the same thread (main)
            Log.i(TAG, "uncaught exception in the thread '"+ thread.getName()+ "' (id="+thread.getId() + "), closing the camera");
            Log.i(TAG, "handled in the thread '"+ Thread.currentThread().getName()+ "' (id="+Thread.currentThread().getId() + ")");
            ex.printStackTrace();

            // .....
            // CLOSE SOMETHING
            // ......

            Log.i(TAG, "going to execute the previous handler: "+mOldUncaughtExceptionHandler);
            if(mOldUncaughtExceptionHandler != null) {
                // it displays the "force close" dialog
                mOldUncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(thread, ex);
            }
        }
    };
    void init() {
        mThread = Thread.currentThread();
        UncaughtExceptionHandler oldUncaughtExceptionHandler = mThread.getUncaughtExceptionHandler();
        if (oldUncaughtExceptionHandler != mUncaughtExceptionHandler) {
            mOldUncaughtExceptionHandler = oldUncaughtExceptionHandler; 
            mThread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(mUncaughtExceptionHandler);
            Log.d(TAG,"~~~ UnexpectedTermination init stuff, doing setUncaughtExceptionHandler");
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG,"~~~ UnexpectedTermination init stuff, skipping setUncaughtExceptionHandler");
        }
        Log.d(TAG,"~~~ UnexpectedTermination init stuff, mThread="+mThread+" mOldUncaughtExceptionHandler="+mOldUncaughtExceptionHandler);
    }
    void fini() {
        Log.d(TAG,"~~~ UnexpectedTermination windup stuff, mThread="+mThread+" mOldUncaughtExceptionHandler="+mOldUncaughtExceptionHandler);
        if (mThread != null) {
            mThread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(mOldUncaughtExceptionHandler);
            mOldUncaughtExceptionHandler = null;
            mThread = null;
        }
    }
}
```

To use it, call `mUnexpectedTerminationStuff.init()` and `mUnexpectedTerminationStuff.fini()` in appropriate places, and replace the "CLOSE SOMETHING" comment with something useful.